# Multiple Asynchronous Request

Tags: jquery

All, I am working on a DashBoard which is required partially update for UI content, And I tried to implement it with asynchronous `Jquery.ajax`, But I found the asynchronous requests totally doesn't work. All the content was updated only when the last reqeusts were finished. So I made a small test and try to find out what happen to it.

Below is my code. please review it.

In the asp.net Page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnMultipleRequest").bind("click", function () {
                $("#imgLoading").show();
                $("#divResponse").empty();
                loopRequest();
            });

            $("#imgLoading").hide();
        });

        function loopRequest() {
            var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            $.each(arr, function () {
                var i = this;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    async: false,
                    url: "server.aspx?waittime=" + i,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divResponse").append("<br>" + data);
                        if (data == "5") {
                            $("#imgLoading").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="btnMultipleRequest" value="BeginMultipleRequest" type="button" />
        <img src="img/wait.gif" id="imgLoading" alt=""/>
        <div id="divResponse">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code-behind code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sTime = Request.Params["WaitTime"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTime))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(sTime) * 1000);
            Response.Write(sTime);
        }
    }
```

The test result is it only works in the firefox ,I mean in firefox all the requests are independent, the page update doesn't wait for all the reponse of requests to be finished.  But not work in the IE and Chrome. because the page will be updated until the last request is over. I don't know if I miss something , please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are doing here is calling ajax call with `async false` which makes it synchronous so try to modify your code and remove `async: false,`

Comment: Hi, @iBlue, Actually with the above sample code , I got different result in the different browser. This makes me confused. Did you know why? thanks.